# Python - TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have the following code portion:

```
names = unpickle('batch')
    print('names', names)

    data, labels = [], []
    filename = 'batch'
    batch_data = unpickle(filename)
    for i in range(0, 2):
        if len(data) > 0:
            data = np.vstack((data, batch_data[0][i]))
            labels = np.hstack((labels, batch_data[1][i]))
        else:
            data = batch_data[0][0]
            labels = batch_data[1][0]

    data = data.astype(np.float32)
```

When this portion is called, I get the following error:

```
names [array([1, 1]), array(['118.jpg', '119.jpg'],
      dtype='<U7'), array([[130, 136, 139, ..., 156, 150, 152],
       [151, 156, 161, ..., 160, 173, 171]])]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "cnn.py", line 6, in <module>
    name, data, labels = cifar_tools.read_data('C:\\Users\\abc\\Desktop\\temp')
  File "C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Testing\cifar_tools.py", line 36, in read_data
    if len(data) > 0:
TypeError: object of type 'numpy.int32' has no len()
```

**EDIT**

This is how the `data` binary file looks like:

```
[array([1, 1]), array(['118.jpg', '119.jpg'], 
      dtype='<U7'), array([[130, 136, 139, ..., 156, 150, 152],
       [151, 156, 161, ..., 160, 173, 171]])]
```

How can I fix this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: After `data = batch_data[0][0]`, what are you expecting `data` to be?

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. The errors seems to show up before reaching that line. It happens on "if len(data) > 0:". The data will be the pixels of the image.

Comment: `if len(data) > 0` happens more than once, you know.

Comment: I have added how the binary file looks like if that helps

Answer (score 0):

First time in the loop, `data` is `[]` so it takes the`else` branch.  2nd time `data` is `batch_data[0][0]`.  So what is that?  Evidently it's `np.int32`, and element of an array.  So it doesn't have a length.

```
data = []
....
for i in range(0, 2):
    if len(data) > 0:
        data = np.vstack((data, batch_data[0][i]))
        labels = np.hstack((labels, batch_data[1][i]))
    else:
        data = batch_data[0][0]
        labels = batch_data[1][0]
```

When do a loop like this, make sure variables like `data` have the same or compatible types at each iteration.  If `data` starts as a list, it should remain a list, through out the loop.

A correct iterative solution using list append

```
data, labels = [], []
filename = 'batch'
batch_data = unpickle(filename)
for i in range(0, 2):
    data.append(batch_data[0][i])
    labels.append(batch_data[1][i])
data = np.array(data, dtype=float)
labels = np.array(labels) # or leave as list?
```

With list append you don't have to test for the len()==0 special case

But I wonder if you even need the loop:

```
data = np.array(batch_data[0]))
labels = np.array(batch_data[1])
```

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply. What should I do in this case to solve the error?

Comment: Added suggestions using list append.